# Let the user to give star rating

Tags: excel, rating, vba

I wonder if anyone could help me with a `star rating` of a specific row in Excel not based on any give number or any information, just based on the user idea, some thing like most websites use to collect feedback from their clients. Then a user could give one to five stars to a written content in a row.

Comment: See [icon sets](http://chandoo.org/wp/2015/08/15/incell-5-star-chart/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a little excel-file example that is attached.
also a little code .

See code below:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H2:L8")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("H2:L8").Rows(Target.Row - 1).Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        Range("H2:H8").Rows(Target.Row - 1).Resize(1, Target.Column - Range("H2").Column + 1).Font.ColorIndex = 6
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Range("G2:G8"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        ' No stars
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 5).Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End If

End Sub
```

See  attached file
 [Here is my Excelfile](https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/4ea9abbf2a8bf5719e363667d65d0a0a20160224161246/57c91b7ca1b85069813b1d439ae0e79920160224161246/b1c7a8)

Have a nice day

Comment: Thank you, it works as I wanted, now I am working on it to understand your code and see if I could apply that on Google Sheets as well. One more time, Thanks.